# useEffect conditional rendering not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, next.js

It seems useEffect triggering a fetch request even though the isMobile state is true.

```
useEffect(() => {
const getData = async () => {
  // Conditionally fetch data only if isMobile is false
  if (isMobile) {
    return;
  }
  const res = await fetchClientApi("Test", 10);
  setData(res);
};

getData();
}, [isMobile]);
```

Array() []
true ---- On initial render ...

Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
true ----- after page loaded

This is the isMobile hook and everything seems to be fine there

```
const useWindowSize = () => {
const [isWindowSizeBelow992, setIsWindowSizeBelow992] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
const handleResize = () => {
  setIsWindowSizeBelow992(window.innerWidth < 992);
};

// Initial check on mount
handleResize();

// Attach event listener for window resize
window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

// Clean up the event listener on unmount
return () => {
  window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
};
}, []);

return isWindowSizeBelow992;
};
```

How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `useWindowSize` will return `false` on the first render, so that the `if (isMobile) {` condition will be skipped. So the call will be made

In order to solve that you can initialize the state of the hook with undefined

```js
- const [isWindowSizeBelow992, setIsWindowSizeBelow992] = useState(false);
+ const [isWindowSizeBelow992, setIsWindowSizeBelow992] = useState(undefined);
```

And in your `getData` you explicitly say that you need the value to be false.
On first render it will be `undefined` and then when useEffect is triggered it will set state correctly based on window resolution ;)

```js
const getData = async () => {
  // Conditionally fetch data only if isMobile is false
  if (isMobile === false) {
    const res = await fetchClientApi("Test", 10);
    setData(res);
  }
};
```

BONUS : you can add a throttle on the resize